# Queries about the ReminderMinutesBeforeStart property

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have been encouraged to ask this question on SO instead of GitHub:

According to the [prototype](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/6889f68d201f5dfbac7258451d97febaeab90420/src/Microsoft.Graph/Models/Generated/Event.cs) for `ReminderMinutesBeforeStart`:

```cs
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore, 
              PropertyName = "reminderMinutesBeforeStart", 
              Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default)]
public Int32? ReminderMinutesBeforeStart { get; set; }
```

I have a few questions all pertaining to this property.

1. In the **Outlook Web App** interface it presents:

[image: reminders]

Why does it present **None** and **0 minutes**? **None** makes sense. **0 minutes** doesn't IMHO.

2. The maximum value presented in the above drop list is **2 weeks**. Is this the official limit? I can't see it documented. If it is the limit, can it be expanded to **4 weeks** so that it is as competitive as the **Google** reminder interval?
3. What exactly happens if we use a value larger than the 2 weeks or a negative value? Is this documented?

Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. `0 minutes` will trigger a reminder when the event happens. If you've scheduled an event at `2:00 PM` and set the reminder of `0 minutes` it will pop a reminder at exactly `2:00 PM`. If you set the reminder for `5 minutes`, a reminder will pop at at 1:55 PM. If you've set it for `None` then it will not pop any reminder.
2. Every UI has to make choices on what it displayed to a user. This property is scoped to minutes which means the value could be 0,1,2,3,4,5,etc. but showing *every possible option* would make the UI unusable. Therefore some choices are made about what is reasonable.
3. The class defines the property as `Int32?` so it could theoretically be set as high as `2,147,483,647` (which represents more than 4000 years). Clearly that would be an irrational value. For `4 Weeks`, simply set it for `40320`.

Comment: Thanks. For your first comment, from a developer point of view, what value do I use then for "None"? Do I use null? For your third comment, then you are saying there is no limit. Google caps it at 4 weeks. So I can use the same cap.

Comment: Ah, I guess if someone chooses None, then isReminderOn is set to false. The interval doesn't matter as it is ignored.

Comment: And I now see that if the reminder is a custom value it is simply formatted and added to the list of static choices. Good. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: "None" ==  `null`, yes. This is why the property is defined as `Int32?` the `?` denotes that this value can be "any 32-bit integer or null".

Comment: `IsReminderOn = bSetReminder, ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = bSetReminder ? iReminderMinutes : null,` It doesn't like the `ReminderMinutesBeforeStart ` assignment.

Comment: Got it: `ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = bSetReminder ? iReminderMinutes : (int?)null`. It just surprises me that `IsReminderOn ` doesn't override everything anyway.

Comment: Setting `IsReminderOn` to false will also disable the reminder. From a data consistency standpoint however, it shouldn't hurt clear `ReminderMinuteBeforeStart` as well.