# Why am I getting an exception when creating a calendar event with no reminder (using Microsoft Graph)?

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I have also asked this question on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/1917). This code raises an exception:

```
// Add the event
Event createdEvent = await _graphClient.Me.Calendars[oSettings.CalendarID].Events.PostAsync(new Event
{
    Subject = oEvent.GetSubject(),
    Body = body,
    Start = startTime,
    End = endTime,
    IsAllDay = oEvent.IsAllDayEvent(),
    IsReminderOn = bSetReminder,
    ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = bSetReminder ? iReminderMinutes : (int?)null,
    Location = location,
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = extendedProperties,
    Sensitivity = oSettings.SetCalendarPrivate ? Sensitivity.Private : Sensitivity.Normal
});
```

I think the issue has to be with this line of code:

```
ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = bSetReminder ? iReminderMinutes : (int?)null
```

Because, if `bSetReminder` is `true`, then I don't get an exception.

The exception happens when `bSetReminder` is `false`. The exception:

```
<LogEntry Date="2023-05-22 16:30:40" Severity="Exception" Source="OutlookCalIFConsole.Outlook+&lt;AddEventToCalendar&gt;d__18.MoveNext" ThreadId="6">
  <Exception Type="Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError" Source="Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter+&lt;ThrowIfFailedResponse&gt;d__28.MoveNext">
    <Message>Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.</Message>
    <StackTrace>   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.&lt;ThrowIfFailedResponse&gt;d__28.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.&lt;SendAsync&gt;d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Kiota.Http.HttpClientLibrary.HttpClientRequestAdapter.&lt;SendAsync&gt;d__20`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Me.Calendars.Item.Events.EventsRequestBuilder.&lt;PostAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at OutlookCalIFConsole.Outlook.&lt;AddEventToCalendar&gt;d__18.MoveNext()</StackTrace>
  </Exception>
</LogEntry>
```

Please see [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46158096/2287576) which has an answer. I am sure this used to work but in the recent Graph releases it now fails. Advice welcomed.

---

#### Update

I tried to obtain addition exception information but this provided no more info:

```
catch (Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError ex)
{
    SimpleLog.Log(ex);
    SimpleLog.Log(ex.InnerException);
    return false;
}
```

As suggested in the answer, if I adjust the code:

```
Event createdEvent = await _graphClient.Me.Calendars[oSettings.CalendarID].Events.PostAsync(new Event
{
    Subject = oEvent.GetSubject(),
    Body = body,
    Start = startTime,
    End = endTime,
    IsAllDay = oEvent.IsAllDayEvent(),
    IsReminderOn = bSetReminder,
    ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = bSetReminder ? iReminderMinutes : 0 /* (int?)null */ ,
    Location = location,
    SingleValueExtendedProperties = extendedProperties,
    Sensitivity = oSettings.SetCalendarPrivate ? Sensitivity.Private : Sensitivity.Normal
});
```

This will work with no exception. I agree that this is version 5 of the SDK, but when I lookup the definition of the property:

```
public int? ReminderMinutesBeforeStart {
    get { return BackingStore?.Get<int?>("reminderMinutesBeforeStart"); }
    set { BackingStore?.Set("reminderMinutesBeforeStart", value); }
}
```

It is still `int?` so I don't understand why `(int?)null` was no longer valid.

But, for now I will change it as the accepted answer. But, I would like more concrete explanation about why my code fails now in V5 of SDK.

Comment: Could you please debug your code and check details of Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError? It would be usefule to see what error code and message is returned.

Answer (score 2):

If `bSetReminder` is `false` then set `ReminderMinutesBeforeStart` to `0` not to `null`.

```
// Add the event
Event createdEvent = await _graphClient.Me.Calendars[oSettings.CalendarID].Events.PostAsync(new Event
{
    ...
    IsReminderOn = bSetReminder,
    ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = bSetReminder ? iReminderMinutes : 0,
    ...
});
```

Comment: Ok. But the linked question comments implied null is for None and 0 for 0 minutes.

Comment: Linked issue is related to older version of SDK. For SDK v5, I think that when ReminderMinutesBeforeStart is not set then the property is not included in the request. But when you set ReminderMinutesBeforeStart to null then SDK v5 includes the property in the request and set the value to null which leads to an exception.